# PhantomJS + CMYK color css3

Tags: css, phantomjs, cmyk

I need to create a pdf from an html document containing text with a color represented in CMYK similar to this example:

```
<div style="color: cmyk(100,0,0,0)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
```

I tried to generate the pdf with 1.9 phantomJS on linux, but the text color is always black.
PhantomJS supports CMYK colors?
How they should be used?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 1.x is based on an old QtWebKit fork from around 2010/2011 or comparable to Chrome 13. Around that time the [CSS Color Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) specification was introduced which doesn't contain a `cmyk` function whereas the current [CSS Color Module Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/) draft contains the `device-cmyk` function.

It is just too new. It is possible that it will be supported in PhantomJS 2.x, but I don't think it will.